# Normal distribution, find $k$ for which $P(20\le X\le k)=0.4641$

Tags: probability-distributions

I am having a problem solving the following.

> Find $k$ such that $$P(20\le X\le k)=0.4641$$ where $X$ is the normal random variable, given mean 20 and variance 4.

I tried finding the $z$ values but got stuck since I can't find a value for $k$. I then tried integrating the standard function of the normal distribution, however I ended up with the wrong answer.

Could someone please explain how can I find $k$.

Comment: Did you mean $X$ instead of $Z$? And if it has a standard normal distribution then mean should be 0 and variance should be 1. Did you mean just normal?

Comment: I have edited my question fixing the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(20\le X\le k)=P\left(\frac{20-20}{2}\le\frac{X-20}{2}\le \frac{k-20}{2}\right)=P\left(0\le Z\le \frac{k-20}{2}\right).$$

Now, if you have a table that gives you $P(Z\le z)$ then you have to look for a value $z$ such that $P(Z\le z)=0.9641$ (note that $P(Z\le 0)=0.5).$

You must get $z=1.8.$ So, it only remains to solve

$$\frac{k-20}{2}=1.8.$$

Comment: how did you get P(Z<z)=0.9641? And why is  P(Z<0)=0.5 important?

Comment: It depends on what table you are using. Does your table give the value $P(Z\le z)$ or $P(0\le Z\le z)?$

Comment: My table is for $P(Z<z)$

Comment: So you have to add to the given value $P(Z\le 0)$ which is $0.5$ by symmetry. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much